# Google Cloud Compute Engine API: createVM directly with setMetadata

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I use @google-cloud/compute to create VM instances automatically.

Also I use startup scripts in those instances.

So, firstly I call [Zone.createVM](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Zone#createVM) and then [VM.setMetadata](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/VM#setMetadata).

But in some regions startup script is not running. And it is running after VM reset, so looks like my [VM.setMetadata](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/VM#setMetadata) call is just too late.

In the web-interface we can create VM directly with metadata. But I do not see this ability in API.

Can it be done with API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up a startup script during instance deployment you can provide it as part of the metadata property in the API call:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/instances

{
  ...
  "metadata": {
    "items": [
      {
       "key": "startup-script",
       "value": "#! /bin/bash\n\n# Installs apache and a custom homepage\napt-get update\napt-get install -y apache2\ncat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html\n<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>\n<p>This page was created from a simple start up script!</p>\n</body></html>"
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

See the full reference for the resource "compute.instances" of the Compute Engine API [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances).

Basically, if you are using a Nodejs library to create the instance you are already calling this, so you will only need to add the metadata keys as documented.

Also, if you are doing this frequently I guess it would be more practical if you stored the script in a bucket in GCP and simply add the URI to the metadata like this:

```
  "metadata": {
    "items": [
      {
       "key": "startup-script-url",
       "value": "gs://bucket/myfile"
      }
    ]
  },
```